# npm installing dev dependencies on production

Tags: node.js, deployment, npm, capistrano

I set NODE_ENV to production and tried to install dependencies using a Capfile which contains this:

```
run "cd #{latest_release} && npm config set production=true && npm install --production"
```

or this:

```
run "cd #{latest_release} && npm install --production"
```

but I always get also the dev dependencies, which is annoying because after a few releases all the inodes are taken and I cannot create any other files on the deploy machine.

I set the environment variable like this in the Capfile:

```
set :default_environment, {
 'NODE_ENV' => 'production'
}
run "echo $NODE_ENV"
```

and it echoes the correct value.

If I execute

```
npm install --production
```

from within a shell, it works correctly. The user that makes the capistrano deploy and this shell user are the same, so I'm quite lost. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was:

```
sudo npm link
```

which I ran after the install command and which installs all dependencies. The fix is:

```
sudo npm link --production
```